# Automatically embed multiple icons in a .NET Executable

Tags: .net, winforms, resources, assemblies, icons

I basically have the same issue as this question: [Embed multiple icons in WPF EXE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832583/embed-multiple-icons-in-wpf-exe)

My .NET 2.0 WinForms application currently has this when you click "Change Icon" in explorer:

[image: EVEMon Single Icon]
<sub>(source: [richard-slater.co.uk](http://www.richard-slater.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/EVEMonIconsWhatIHave.png))</sub>

What I would like to see, and with some hacking about as suggested by the above article I get this:

[image: EVEMon Multiple Icons]
<sub>(source: [richard-slater.co.uk](http://www.richard-slater.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/EVEMonIconsWhatIWant.png))</sub>

However the process of getting there all of the version information for the assembly is lost. I need to maintain the Version Information in the assembly as my auto-update process relies on this to identify the installed version of the application.

I also build the application through a continuous integration process so I would prefer not to have any steps that require manual intervention, so is this possible in an automated way?

Comment: Doesn't adding icons as resources suffice?

Comment: Adding the icons as a .NET Resource (.resx) won't make them available to Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've just created a simple tool to do exactly this without having to mess with .res files. It is a tiny utility which you can use as part of your Post-Build event and lets you add all icon files in a particular folder to your assembly. If we assume that you have a icons folder under your main project folder you can add the following post-build event:

```
C:\path\to\InsertIcons.exe $(TargetPath) $(ProjectDir)icons
```

A further description and a download can be found at http://einaregilsson.com/add-multiple-icons-to-a-dotnet-application/

Comment: Sweet.  I especially appreciate that InsertIcons is open-source and on  [github](https://github.com/einaregilsson/InsertIcons).

Comment: Thanks for the utility.  Works like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

The article mentioned by ChrisF will also wipe out your assembly version information.  Once you follow that guide you might want to try using the post-build method described here [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/cheller/how-to-embed-a-manifest-in-an-assembly-let-me-count-the-ways) to embed the manifest.

EDIT:

It is "Method #2 - The "Generic" Approach (using mt.exe)"

Comment: Thanks for looking into that further for me, I shall have a look at the CodeProject guide and the blog see if I can build up an automated process.

Answer (score 2):

This [Code Project article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/embedmultipleiconsdotnet.aspx) has a walkthrough on how to do this.

Basically you add more icon resources to the project.

Comment: Looks promising, I shall have a go tomorrow see if this does everything I need.

Comment: That article does not solve his versioning problems, it seems to stop the manifest from being embedded.

Answer (score 1):

For me the simplest solution to that problem is to create a .res file, which includes only icons you need (and stores them in your preferred order), disable a main icon in project properties and merge previously prepared icon pack (.res file) to your final .exe file, doing it in post-build event. Although, if this process can be fully automated and keep your manifest data unchanged, it needs in last step a external tool (**ResHacker**), which allow you to do a .res file merging job via command line (of course, Visual Studio can do this, but as far I know there are no command line interface to achieve it - if I'm wrong, please correct me).

1. Download a blank .res file (http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/160885/How-to-Embed-Multiple-Icons-and-Color-Animated-Cur.aspx) and add it to your project
2. Fill out previously added .res file with your icons
3. Remove main icon from your project (Project -> Properties)
4. Download a *ResHacker* tool (http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) and place it wherever you want
5. Add similar line to your post-build event:

   ```
   if $(ConfigurationName) == Release (
     ..\..\..\..\..\Tools\ResHack\ResHacker.exe -add $(TargetPath), $(TargetPath), $(ProjectDir)Properties\AssemblyWin32.res ,,,
   )
   ```

That's all. Everytime you compile your project in Release mode you will get a wanted icons to your destination .exe file.

Comment: Yes, it does. Moreover the ResHacker tool allows you control entire resource data included in your .exe file, e.g. instead of merging other .res file into it, you can just add some icon or replace it, whatever you want to do. Note that a major feature of this tool is command line usability.