# embed project icon in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

This problem is getting me crazy, I really have no clue what's going on - why it's not working as I think it should.

I have a WPF C# project. I've added a directory named "ExtFiles" to my solution. This directory contains a ICO file, a PNG image and TTF font.

All three files have "build action" set to "resource", and "copy to output dir" set to "Do not copy".

I call these 3 files in the XAML via:

For the Icon:

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:chartingToolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit" x:Class="Swiftech_Imperium.MainWindow"
        Title="Imp" Height="435" Width="510" ResizeMode="CanMinimize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Icon="pack://application:,,,/ExtFiles/imp.ico"
```

For the Image:

```
<Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="278" Height="30" Margin="9,401,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="pack://application:,,,/ExtFiles/Logo.png"/>
```

And for the font:

```
<Label x:Name="LabelTemp1" BorderBrush="#FFFFA421" BorderThickness="1" FontFamily="pack://application:,,,/ExtFiles/#DS-Digital" Height="30"
```

Everything works, no error. The image is displaying, the icon too, the font is working.

But, when I publish, it does generate the ExtFile directory with the icon in it. Why is that? My goal is to have all 3 files embedded in the EXE. My goal is deploy the program using the single EXE file and nothing else, as the users's requirement.

All these 3 files are called only in the XAML and nowhere else, I don't understand why it's working fine for the image and font but not for the icon...

Any idea?

Thanks
Steve

Edit: I tried this: [Embed multiple icons in WPF EXE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832583/embed-multiple-icons-in-wpf-exe) (last answer) but it doesn't work.

```
Icon="/Resources/Imp.ico"

Source="/Resources/Logo.png"

FontFamily="/Resources/#DS-Digital"
```

I get this error (only for the icon, If I can the Icon=".." out it starts but the image and the font are not applied...

```
'System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension' threw an exception.' Line number '5' and line position '9'.
```

I added the 3 files as resources (Resource, add file) and set their build action to "resource".

edit:

OK... I moved forward a tiny bit.

I added both DLL's (yeah there two!) to the resources.
Moved the image/icon/font to a separate folder (that probably wasn't needed).

but I was still getting the same error (parsing).

turns out it is my XAML that is calling the second DLL (which I originally forgot to add to the resources).

Now with both DLL's as resources, if I go into References and set both of these DLL's Copy Local to False, I get an error. I can put the first dll (WPFToolkit.dll) to false, but I can't do for system.windows.controls.datavisualization.toolkit.dll :(

reason why is because the XAML is calling it:

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:chartingToolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit" x:Class="Imperium.MainWindow"
        Title="Imperium" Height="435" Width="510" ResizeMode="CanMinimize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Icon="pack://application:,,,/ExtFiles/Imp.ico" Closing="Window_Closing" MouseDown="Grid_MouseDown" WindowStyle="None" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Foreground="Black">
```

what can I do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832583/embed-multiple-icons-in-wpf-exe

Comment: Thanks but doesn't work.

Comment: Did you tried `EmbeddedResource` action as well? Is there any publishing setting which you may try to toggle? Just a bit of hint only.

Answer (score 0):

Your pack URN was wrong for the icon. It should be:

> pack://application:,,,/(qualified assembly name i.e. My.Project.Executable);component/ExtFiles/imp.ico

When you add the file to the VS project folder you should set it as `Resource` with `Do Not Copy`.

The same applies for the image and the font - tho' I would also say that I've not loaded font using a direct reference like this and I'm not sure it works like this.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:
Doing with Resources would be a different approach to achieve the same task. I would like to provide you a link to read certain msdn articles.

[Adding and Editing Resources (Visual C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference